# Systemi navigator Moving Schema from one Lpar to another (RDB entry)

Tags: ibm-midrange, navigator

we are having trouble copying database tables from a schema on one logical partition to another on our power i system. We are doing this in systemi navigator and getting an RDB directory entry error.

Is anyone familiar with setting up the RDB entries between lpars on an AS/400 system?

is this the correct syntax for the "ADDRDBIRE" command, assuming this set up?

Lpar1 ip adress = ***.***..42,  database name: Poweri
Lpar2 ip adress = ***.***..48,  database name: b11fdev

*ADDRDBIRE RDB(Poweri) RMTLOCNAME(B11fdev)

Comment: Syntax is correct; but the values seem wrong. On LPAR1, you'd want something more like `RDB(B11fdev) RMTLOCNAME(B11fdev)`. You'll want the RDB() name to somehow reflect the remote system; and you should already have `RDB(Poweri)` defined on LPAR1 as the `*LOCAL` entry.

Comment: So the correct syntax would be: *ADDRDBIRE RDB(B11fdev) RMTLOCNAME(Ip adress, or B11fdev)?

Comment: Assuming that "B11fdev" is the name of the database on the B11FDEV system, then that should about right. If B11FDEV is defined in your DNS (or in the hosts table on LPAR1), you can use it as the RMTLOCNAME() name. If it can't be resolved by a DNS query, then you'll have to use the IP address instead of the name. You can always add the entry, test it and remove it if it doesn't work. The database needs to be registered first on the B11FDEV system before other systems can connect to it.